Wave Analytics deployment error
I am facing error while running the dataflow.
I have created an Analytics event monitoring app using template.I created a dashboard using datasets which were created with App. When I am trying to deploy it to org (App,dataflow,  dashboard and all datasets), deployment is successful but datasets are not visible in UI. Also, when I try to run a dataflow it give me an below error
Something went wrong while executing the ExtractProcessedApexUnexpectedException node: Error in GetEdgemartCurrentData for edgemart ApexUnexpectedExceptionProcessed [error category: USER]: No edgemarts found with specified URL:esObject/edgemart?current=true&alias=ApexUnexpectedExceptionProcessed (02KKH000000ThNV2A0_03CKH000000QCTv2AO)

Deployment of template apps is currently not supported.  Try to create new version of templated apps in destination environment. (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394606&type=1)
